# Javascript search for string match and display no duplicates

Tags: javascript, xml, match, indexof

Here's my XML

```
<document>
    <item>
    <my_summary>The cow jump over the moon</my_summary>
    </item>
    <item>
    <my_summary>Pepper piper keeper moon</my_summary>
    </item>
    <item>
    <my_summary>The swan flew jump the lake</my_summary>
    </item>
    <item>
    <my_summary>moon stars blue yellow</my_summary>
    </item>
    </document>
```

Here's my javascript loop code

```
var count_my_summary =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
var keywords = "Over moon";
var filtered_array_exclude = keywords.match(/\w+/g).map(function(i) {return i.toLowerCase();}).filter(function(i) { return exclusionlist.indexOf(i) == -1; }) 
var filtered_array = new removeDuplicateElement(filtered_array_exclude);


for (xml_i=0;xml_i<count_my_summary.length;xml_i++){ 
     for (var i = 0; i < filtered_array.length; i++) {
        var xml_summary_lowercase = count_my_summary[xml_i].getElementsByTagName("my_summary")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toLowerCase();
        var result = xml_summary_lowercase.indexOf(keyword,0);
        if (result > -1) {
        document.write(my_summary + "<br><br>");
        } else {
        document.write("");
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

The result of this code will loop into the my_summary and then display when there's a match. There's a duplication of result, because it will for "over" or "moon"

```
The cow jump over the moon - for "over" match
The cow jump over the moon - for "moon" match
Pepper piper keeper moon - for "moon" match
moon stars blue yellow - for "moon" match
```

My target result is to remove duplicates... for this example remove "The cow jump over the moon"

```
The cow jump over the moon - for "over " and "moon" match
Pepper piper keeper moon - for "moon" match
moon stars blue yellow - for "moon" match
```

How can I make this search by "over" AND "moon" and if there's a match, then don't display the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

i would have done it differently. i would use jquery to get the elements I need then you can output them as you'd like. the filter function checks each element to match the filter words. this way you wont have duplicates since it iterates each element only once (internally maybe more due to the for loop)

```
var filterString = "moon over";
var filterArr = filterString.split(" ");

$(xmlDoc).find("my_summary").filter(function(){
for(var str in filterArr){
if ($(this).text().search(str) > -1)
return true;
}
return false;
});
```